# How to un-check radio button that appear in ItemsControl ?

Tags: silverlight

I define ItemControl that contain Radio Button.

```
       <ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItemList}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Content="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Now, I want to un-checked all the radioButton that the ItemsControl contain. 
I want to write some method that will un-checked all those radioButton. 
How can i do it ?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can see that the radio buttons are binded to `myItemList`.
Add another property (for the example named `IsChecked`.)
Make the method run on `myItemList` and set all the `IsChecked` properties to false.

Make sure the `IsChecked` property raises [PropetyChangedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx).

For example:

If `myItemList` is `List(of Bla)` and `Bla` has the property `Key` and `IsChecked`.
A simple For each loop can do the job:

```
For Each blaItem as Bla in myItemList
   blaItem.IsChecked = false
Next
```

The xaml look like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItemList}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding Path=Key}" Checked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: The myItemList is List that contain object that one of the object properties is Key - So i cant make the run on the myItemList to be un-checked

Comment: As i said before ... the myItemList memberts contain the blaItem.Key but this is not bool object ( ! ) ==> this is string that will be binding to the RadioButton as the RadioButton content( that mean the string that will appear in the Radio button )

Comment: In this case you can just use a String to Boolean Converter on the binding to solve it. See the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Comment: Thanks michael - but this is not what i need. i just need to know how to scan the GUI object child and find the right item and un check it.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding but you haven't mentioned GUI objects in the question. Anyway, it will be easier to add another property and bind _Checked_ property as well. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I dont have one more property because the items. I solve this issue - code attached.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem and this is the code ...

```
foreach( var item in myItemList.Items )
        {
            DependencyObject presenter = CategoryBar.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem( item );

            RadioButton t = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild( presenter, 0 ) as RadioButton;

            if( t != null && t.IsChecked == true )
            {
                t.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
```